# Best way to replace a beginning and end character in Perl using Regular Expression?

Tags: performance, perl, regex

I'm wondering if there is a simplier regex I could use in my code to remove the beginning and ending char in a line. Maybe combine some regex's? In this instance, it's a comma at the beginning and ending of a line. My output should be the fields seperated into CSV format.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

parse_DPCRS();

sub parse_DPCRS {
    open ( FILEIN, 'txt_files/AKR_DPCRS.txt' );
    open ( FILEOUT, '>txt_files/AKR_DPCRS.csv' );
    while (<FILEIN>) {
        next if /^(\s)*$/;          #skip blank lines
        next if /^\>/;              #skip command line that start with >
        next if /^\s+POINT\sCODE/;  #skip header
        next if /^\s+NODE\sNAME/;   #skip header
        next if /^\s+\=+/;          #skip header
        next if /^\s+CCS\sDPCRS/;   #skip pageination footer
        chomp;                      #removing trailing newline character
        s/\s+/,/g;                  #replace white space with a comma
        s/^,//;                     #replace beginning comma with empty
        s/,$//;                     #replace ending comma with empty
        my (
            $nodeName, $pointCodeDec ) =  split( "," );
        print FILEOUT ($nodeName . "," . $pointCodeDec . "\n");
        #print "$_\n";
    }
};
close (FILEOUT);
close (FILEIN);
exit;
```

Here's a slice of the text file I'm parsing

```
>DISP CCS DPCRS ALL 0

                 POINT CODE  POINT CODE  TYPE OF  ROUTESET  NOTIFY   NODE
   NODE NAME      DECIMAL        HEX      ROUTE    MASTER    SCCP  LOCATION
   ===========  ===========  ==========  =======  ========  ====== ========
   PBVJPRCO01T  1-1-1          010101    FULL PC      119     NO    NON-ADJ
   ROCHNYXA06T  1-6-1          010601    FULL PC       58     NO    NON-ADJ
   NYCNNYDRW17  1-6-2          010602    FULL PC       58     NO    NON-ADJ
   SYRCNYSW01T  1-6-3          010603    FULL PC       22     NO    NON-ADJ
   SYRCNYSWDS0  1-6-15         01060F    FULL PC       58     NO    NON-ADJ
   ROCHNYFEDS0  1-6-17         010611    FULL PC       58     NO    NON-ADJ
   NYCMNYHD01T  1-9-11         01090B    FULL PC       22     NO    NON-ADJ
   NWRKNJ1001T  1-9-14         01090E    FULL PC       22     NO    NON-ADJ
   BSTNMABL01T  1-9-16         010910    FULL PC       22     NO    NON-ADJ
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a single regex that removes `,` (comma) at the beginig or at the end of a string:

```
$str =~ s/^,+|,+$//g;
```

and here is a benchmark that compares this regex with a double one:

```
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $str = q/,a,b,c,d,/;
my $count = -3;
cmpthese($count, {
        'two regex' => sub {
            $str =~ s/^,+//;
            $str =~ s/,+$//;
        },
        'one regex' => sub {
            $str =~ s/^,+|,+$//g;
        },
    });
```

**The result:**

```
               Rate one regex two regex
one regex  597559/s        --      -58%
two regex 1410348/s      136%        --
```

We can see that two regex are really faster than one regex that combines the two.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a tricky regexp, but wouldn't you be better served by creating the string using a combination of split and join?

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html

The examples in the middle show different combinations to split based on word boundaries.
There are also examples that show how to get matching splits for the last and first character.

Hope thIs helps

Answer (score 1):

I try to run your code, and i don't understand what do you want on exit?
I'll see first two colums, if what you want you need to use `print "$1,$2\n"`

Try to use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
  print "$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7\n" if /(\w{11})\s+(\d+-\d+-\d+)\s+(\w{6})\s+(\w.*?)\s+(\d+)\s+(\w.*?)\s+(\w.*?)$/gs
}
```

usage:

```
txt2csv.pl txt_files/AKR_DPCRS.txt > txt_files/AKR_DPCRS.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how I might do that.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.1;

my $input_filename = 'test.in';
my $output_filename = 'test.out';

open my $input, '<', $input_filename;

my $pack = '';

# throw out everything before "=====" line
while( <$input> ){
  if( /^\s*=[\s=]+$/ ){
    # use "=====" line to calculate lengths and offsets

    # split on \s [=] boundary keeping everything
    my @elem = split /(\s+)/;

    my $pos = 0;
    for (@elem){
      my $length = length $_;
          if( /=/ ){
        $pack .= '@'.$pos.'A'.$length;
      }
      $pos += $length;
    }

    last; # stop skipping lines
  }
}
# at this point the iterator for $input is after "=====" line

{
  open my $output, '>', $output_filename;
  for my $line ( <$input> ){
    say {$output} join ',', unpack $pack, $line;
  }
  close $output;
}
close $input;
```

This code will continue to work if the width of the columns, or number of columns change.